# Program counter traverse

Tags: mips

What is the maximum distance that a program counter can traverse in memory, as a result of a jump instruction? I know the answer is 2^28 bytes, but I don't know why it is 2^28 instead of 2^26 bytes

Thank you

Comment: This is not a site for "why is it so" or "please explain" questions. Rather it is a site for getting specific answers to specific software problems one is facing.

Comment: Read the description of `J` in _MIPS32™ Architecture For Programmers Volume II: The MIPS32™ Instruction Set_.